# What is the population ratio of humans and pokemon?

Tags: pokemon

What is the population ratio of humans and pokemon in the pokemon world (pokemon series)? Considering that every human has more than one pokemon, it might be possible the pokemon ratio is higher.

Comment: It is possible that pokemon's ratio is higher than humans. Like the animals in the wild in real world, there are pokemons in the wild in the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any specific information about this in the Pokémon anime, manga, or games, but the ratio of humans to Pokémon in the Pokémon world is likely similar to the ratio of humans to other animals in the real world. The estimates listed below are from this article: [How Many Wild Animals Are There](http://reducing-suffering.org/how-many-wild-animals-are-there/#Summary_table). The author admitted the estimates are not very good, but I could not find a better source.

Land Birds: 1 * 10<sup>11</sup> to 4 * 10<sup>11</sup>
Land Mammals: 10<sup>11</sup> to 10<sup>12</sup>
Land Reptiles: 10<sup>11</sup> to 10<sup>12</sup>
Land Amphibians: 10<sup>11</sup> to 10<sup>13</sup>
Fish: 10<sup>13</sup> to 10<sup>15</sup>
Humans: 7 * 10<sup>9</sup>

From these, we can get a rough calculation of the ratio of other animals to humans (and thus Pokémon to humans) by summing the different groups of animals (using the higher estimates) and dividing by the number of humans:

1.0124 * 10<sup>15</sup> animals / 7 * 10<sup>9</sup> humans = **144,628 animals per human**.

This number should give a general idea of the ratio between humans and animals, but should in no way be taken as accurate. And note that if I added arthropods into the sum, then the ratio would be greater by several orders of magnitude. I didn't do so because bug Pokémon are much larger than their real world counterparts and their populations probably would not be comparable as a result.

Links of interest:

- [Lists of organisms by population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_organisms_by_population)
- [About how big is the bird population? Has it gone down because of global warming or pollution?](http://www.amnh.org/ology/features/askascientist/question16.php)